# Java client/server validation: if jtextfield empty?

Tags: java, if-statement, dialog, int, messagedialog

For a textfield that is empty using client side validation with message dialog pop up boxes how do you code it for `integer` and `double`?

I implemented the `String empname` however I can't seem to make a dialog box pop up for `empid` and `payrate`, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
String empname = jtfEname.getText();
    //If no text is entered display pop up dialog box.
if(empname.length()==0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Name");

int empid = Integer.parseInt(jtfEid.getText().trim());
    //If no id is entered display pop up dialog box.
if (empid.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Id");

double payrate = Double.parseDouble(jtfPayRate.getText().trim());
    //If no payrate is entered display pop up dialog box
if (payrate.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Pay Rate");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int empid; 
try {
    empid = Integer.parseInt(jtfEid.getText().trim());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Id");
}
```

If the user enters anything but `int`, this should open up the Dialog box.
Same thing goes for the `payrate`.

```
double payrate;
try {
    payrate = Double.parseDouble(jtfPayRate.getText().trim());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Pay Rate");
}
```

Comment: Spot on well done thank you for your input, have a awesome day